# ClickOnce Custom Installer - GetManifestAsync Issue

Tags: installation, clickonce

I've borrowed the code from [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Installer for a ClickOnce Application (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/deployment/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-installer-for-a-clickonce-application?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN) and [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Installer for
a ClickOnce Application (VB)](http://www.vb-net.com/VB2015/Technology/ClickOnce.%20Publishing.pdf) to create my own custom installer for our ClickOnce deployment.

I started a new VB.NET project to use as the installer, and added the MyInstaller class shown below.

It looks like the code should work "out of the box" but I'm finding when I call `GetManifestAsync` the `GetManifestCompleted` event never fires.

I've tried passing it a valid URL for the myApp.application as well as a UNC path name for it on my server. I've also tried passing it an *invalid* URL and *invalid* UNC path name just to see if I could even get it to raise an error, but it doesn't do that either when I call `iphm = New InPlaceHostingManager(deploymentUri, False)`.

Since the calls are async I'm calling the `InstallApplication` method and then sitting in a `Do...Loop` waiting for it to complete.

Any thoughts on what I might be missing or doing wrong?

Here's the MyInstaller class:

```
    Public Class MyInstaller
Private WithEvents iphm As InPlaceHostingManager = Nothing

Public Event DownloadProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs)
Public Property IsComplete As Boolean = False

Public Sub InstallApplication(ByVal deployManifestUriStr As String)

    Try
        Dim deploymentUri As New Uri(deployManifestUriStr)
        iphm = New InPlaceHostingManager(deploymentUri, False)
    Catch uriEx As UriFormatException
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot install the application: The deployment manifest URL supplied is not a valid URL. Error: " & uriEx.Message)
        Return
    Catch platformEx As PlatformNotSupportedException
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot install the application: This program requires Windows XP or higher. Error: " & platformEx.Message)
        Return
    Catch argumentEx As ArgumentException
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot install the application: The deployment manifest URL supplied is not a valid URL. Error: " & argumentEx.Message)
        Return
    End Try

    iphm.GetManifestAsync()
End Sub
Private Sub iphm_GetManifestCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GetManifestCompletedEventArgs) Handles iphm.GetManifestCompleted
    ' Check for an error.
    If (e.Error IsNot Nothing) Then
        ' Cancel download and install.
        MessageBox.Show("Could not download manifest. Error: " & e.Error.Message)
        Return
    End If
    ' Dim isFullTrust As Boolean = CheckForFullTrust(e.ApplicationManifest)
    ' Verify this application can be installed.
    Try
        ' the true parameter allows InPlaceHostingManager
        ' to grant the permissions requested in the application manifest.
        iphm.AssertApplicationRequirements(True)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while verifying the application. Error text: " & ex.Message)
        Return
    End Try
    ' Use the information from GetManifestCompleted() to confirm
    ' that the user wants to proceed.
    Dim appInfo As String = "Application Name: " & e.ProductName
    appInfo &= ControlChars.Lf & "Version: " & e.Version.ToString()
    appInfo &= ControlChars.Lf & "Support/Help Requests: "
    If Not (e.SupportUri Is Nothing) Then
        appInfo &= e.SupportUri.ToString()
    Else
        appInfo &= "N/A"
    End If
    appInfo &= ControlChars.Lf & ControlChars.Lf & "Confirmed that this application can run with its requested permissions."
    ' If isFullTrust Then
    ' appInfo &= ControlChars.Lf & ControlChars.Lf & _
    ' "This application requires full trust in order to run."
    ' End If
    appInfo &= ControlChars.Lf & ControlChars.Lf & "Proceed with installation?"
    Dim dr As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show(appInfo, "Confirm Application Install", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
    If dr <> System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Return
    End If
    ' Download the deployment manifest.
    ' Usually, this shouldn't throw an exception unless
    ' AssertApplicationRequirements() failed, or you did not call that method
    ' before calling this one.
    Try
        iphm.DownloadApplicationAsync()
    Catch downloadEx As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot initiate download of application. Error: " & downloadEx.Message)
        Return
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub iphm_DownloadProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles iphm.DownloadProgressChanged
    ' you can show percentage of task completed using e.ProgressPercentage
    RaiseEvent DownloadProgressChanged(sender, e)
End Sub
Private Sub iphm_DownloadApplicationCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DownloadApplicationCompletedEventArgs) Handles iphm.DownloadApplicationCompleted
    ' Check for an error.
    If (e.Error IsNot Nothing) Then
        ' Cancel download and install.
        MessageBox.Show("Could not download and install application. Error: " & e.Error.Message)
        Return
    End If
    ' Inform the user that their application is ready for use.
    MessageBox.Show("Application installed! You may now run it from the Start menu.")

    IsComplete = True
End Sub
```

End Class

And here's how I'm calling it:

```
        Dim installer As New MyInstaller()
        installer.InstallApplication("\\myServer\myShare\myApp.application")
        'installer.InstallApplication("http://myServer/myShare/myApp.application")

        Do
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        Loop Until installer.IsComplete

        MessageBox.Show("Installer object created.")
```

Answer (score 0):

I tracked down the source of the problem.

I needed to exit the routine that called `installer.InstallApplication("\\myServer\myShare\myApp.application")`.

I removed the `Do...Loop` and exited the routine and the `GetManifestCompleted` fires like it should.

Whew...